# Android エミュレータにproxyを指定すると起動できない

Tags: android, android-studio

Android エミュレータ（avd）に proxy オプションを付けて起動しようとするとFATALエラーになって起動できません。proxy オプションを付けない場合は起動できます。

解決策はあるでしょうか。

```
C:\Users\jirolabo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_S_API_21 -netspeed full -netdelay none -http-proxy http://xxx:yyy@192.168.1.100:8080
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: device fd:824
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 107 144 433 721
FATAL:.//android/base/sockets/SocketWaiter.cpp:89:Check failed: isValidFd(fd). fd 1332 max1024
Error accepting connection, aborting
```

エミュレータはAndroid Studio（バージョンは1.0.2 ）のメニューから AVD Manager > Create Virtual Device で表示される Virtual Device Configurationのダイアログで作成しました。
System Image は Lollipop、API Level:21、ABI:x86 です。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

確かに、有効な Proxy を指定するとエミュレータウィンドウが表示されてすぐに、落ちますね。

```
> ...\Android\sdk\tools\emulator -avd Nexus_S_API_21 -netspeed full -netdelay none -http-proxy http://127.0.0.1:8123

emulator: device fd:632

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 76 102 308 513
FATAL:.//android/base/sockets/SocketWaiter.cpp:89:Check failed: isValidFd(fd). f
d 1152 max1024
Error accepting connection, aborting
```

stackoverflow 英語版の [Android emulator with proxy settings - Error FATAL:.//android/base/sockets/ Check failed: isValidFd(fd). fd 1404 max1024](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484133/android-emulator-with-proxy-settings-error-fatal-android-base-sockets-chec) で書かれているように、 `-no-audio` オプションを付けて、オーディオサポートを無効にすると起動することができました。

```
> ...\Android\sdk\tools\emulator -avd Nexus_S_API_21 -netspeed full -netdelay none -no-audio -http-proxy http://127.0.0.1:8123

emulator: device fd:628

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 76 102 308 513
```

Comment: 起動できました。ありがとうございます。